# Response from http-request not showing in template

Tags: angular

I am learning http. I follow tutorial from https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html but I can't get my data from response. I have no error. I use JSON typicode json: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

Here my code, same from tutorial, cant find error in my code. Can someone help?

Service

```
  private postsUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'

  getPosts(): Promise<Post[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.postsUrl)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json().data as Post[])
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
  private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }
```

Class

```
export class Post {
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  body: string;
}
```

component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `

  <div *ngFor="let post of posts">
    {{post.title}}
  </div>



  `,
})
export class App implements OnInit {

  posts: Post[] = [];

  constructor(private postsService: PostsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.postsService.getPosts() 
      .then(posts => this.posts = posts)
  }

}
```

I have plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/eEj7vPwf3KjlLkdjAisE?p=preview

Thank you in advance for assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your response does not have a `data` field.

So remove `.data` from

```
.then(response => response.json().data
```

Fixed plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/9bjXi4qhMYlcla9B4nFP?p=preview

Comment: @DRNR does the tutorial use the same url to get the json data?

Comment: @DRNR You can look at the response... the response you are getting is an array, response does not contain an `data` object with an array like `{"data": [{..}, {..}]}` So you just want to assign your response directly to your array, since your response looks like: `[{...},{..}]`

Comment: I see. I misunderstand what data is. Thank you for assistance!